# Attaching circuit boards to form 3D Shape

Tags: connector

I'm at the early design stages of a project and I'm trying to determine the feasibility of   constructing a dodecahedron using PCBs for the 12 faces, similar to [this](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/01/04/x2-time-ball-final-assembly/), however, with an easier method of readily accessing and enclosing the contents instead of cable ties.

My best idea at the moment is to use epoxy to create a lower and upper half of 10 faces each - this way the angles between faces can be fixed - alongside some simple plastic clips to join both sections.

I have looked into some conventional forms of mechanically attaching PCBs, such as castellations, headers and hinged-standoffs, but I haven't managed to come across something that allows a fixed angle other than right angles. Is there something I've overlooked? Can anyone suggest other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNC or 3d Printed connecting shields. For normal use, you would make one piece where the boards slot into place, but there would be slight gaps, depending on the design. For gapless use, you need to make them in two pieces. One for the frontside, one for the backside, on each corner. Designed to meet the angle you want. There would be x number of holes, one for each pcb that is meant to join at that corner. A hole would also be made in the pcb. Then you screw or bolt them together.

Think box corner protectors. [image]

Heck, you could even get them stamped or cut out of metal, if you want the gapless ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was definitely something I considered initially. I may look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention canoes, obliquely, I suggest adapting the "stitch and tape" construction common for small boats to "stitch and solder".

Run fairly broad copper track up to the edge of the PCB on the inside or preferably both sides, and arrange a hole (0.8 or 1mm) close to each end.
Thread copper wire through the holes and twist to align the boards; the form of the icosahedron should allow you to set the angles accurately. Then run a bead of solder along the seams on the inside with a high power iron. Result : two quite rigid halves.

For a better (stronger and neater) job you may want to do the same on the outside; however there is a gap between the tracks. (Plating across the board edge is possible but I won't recommend it because it'll push the PCB price up.
One possible solution : the copper tape that "Tiffany" style stained glass makers use.

For making connections between the boards, break the copper seam into segments on the inside.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I will look into it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a spherical surface and drew the triangles on it, then drilled each triangular area for the LEDs? By using two hemispherical plastic bowls (salad bowls?), you will have easy access to the inside. The problem then degrades to how to hold the halves together and that should be much easier to do. Hint: through bolt.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, I'm not sure how I would integrate the PCBs.